# magento2 soap web service error

Tags: soap, magento2

I created script like this.and I have created token also from admin side.

```
ini_set('display_errors',1);
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-server/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php');
require('vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php');
$token = "e3wcugwhdhqoxccwdli8yxepaih5lm3b";
$opts = ['http' => ['header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $token]];
$context = stream_context_create($opts);

$wsdlUrl = "http://192.168.11.175/magento2/soap?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1,customerCustomerRepositoryV1";
$serviceArgs = array("customerId" => 1);

$soapClient = new \Zend\Soap\Client($wsdlUrl);
$soapClient->setSoapVersion(SOAP_1_2);
$soapClient->setStreamContext($context);
$soapResponse = $soapClient->customerCustomerRepositoryV1GetById($serviceArgs);
var_dump($soapResponse);
```

and I’m getting following error when i run the script.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://192.168.11.175/magento2/soap?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1,customerCustomerRepositoryV1' : failed to load external entity "http://192.168.11.175/magento2/soap?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1,customerCustomerRepositoryV1" in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php:37 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php(37): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://192.168....', Array) #1 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1023): Zend\Soap\Client\Common->__construct(Array, 'http://192.168....', Array) #2 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1195): Zend\Soap\Client->_initSoapClientObject() #3 /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client.php(1106): Zend\Soap\Client->getSoapClient() #4 /var/www/html/magento2/soapcall.php(16): Zend\Soap\Client->__call('cus in /var/www/html/magento2/vendor/zendframework/zend-soap/src/Client/Common.php on line 37
```

Comment: I try run you script and get output like 
`object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["result"]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (12) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
    ["groupId"]=>
    int(1)
     .....
}`
So, maybe problem with access from computer that run script to url http://192.168.11.175/magento2/

Comment: Thanks for your response.means any specific php extensions missing in my system?

Comment: Don't think so, please open "http://192.168.11.175/magento2/soap?wsdl&services=customerAccountManagementV1,customerCustomerRepositoryV1 in brouser, can you see xml?

Answer (score 0):

@sivakumar :

1. $token must be the 'Access Token' in System->Integration->YourApiUserDetail. NOT the 'Access Token Secret'.
2. Check your Magento's base_url. Is it "http://192.168.11.175/magento2/"?
3. If domain gives the error, then u can set it in your host file.

Comment: I have used the access token and my Magento base url is correct too.. But still unable to resolve this error..